# Implementing safe duck-typing in C#

Tags: c#, adapter, duck-typing

After looking at how [Go](http://golang.org/) handles interfaces and liking it, I started thinking about how you could achieve similar duck-typing in C# like this:

```
var mallard = new Mallard(); // doesn't implement IDuck but has the right methods
IDuck duck = DuckTyper.Adapt<Mallard,IDuck>(mallard);
```

The `DuckTyper.Adapt` method would use `System.Reflection.Emit` to build an adapter on the fly. Maybe somebody has already written something like this. I guess it's not too different from what mocking frameworks already do.

However, this would throw exceptions at run-time if `Mallard` doesn't actually have the right `IDuck` methods. To get the error earlier at compile time, I'd have to write a `MallardToDuckAdapter` which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a better way?

**edit**: apparently the proper term for what I call "safe duck-typing" is [structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_typing).

Comment: I've wished for this before, adapting the System.xml.serialization system to work with the generic system.runtime.serialization formatters.

Comment: Also: does Go check this at compile-time, or just run-time? If the latter, they haven't provided any new solutions to the problem, just the extra Adapt code you already mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, writing the adapter would not qualify as duck typing, because it's regular C# typing...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How can you know if a cow walks like a duck and quacks like a duck if you don't have a living, breathing cow in front of you?

Duck-typing is a concept used at run-time. A similar concept at compile-time is [**structural typing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_typing) which is AFAIK not supported by the CLR. (The CLR is centred around [**nominative typing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system).)

> [A structural type system] contrasts with nominative systems, where comparisons are based on explicit declarations or the names of the types, and duck typing, in which only the part of the structure accessed at runtime is checked for compatibility.

The usual way to ensure that duck-typing throws no exception at run-time are unit-tests.

Comment: In Go, duck-typing is something that is verified statically. The compiler looks at the Cow class and complains if it doesn't have the duck methods.

Comment: That's exactly the definition of structural inheritance :-)

Comment: In .NET, duck typing is used differently from the usual meaning of the term. Unfortunately, re-branding established technical terms has become something of a company hobby at Microsoft (or at least in the CLR department), which is extremely annoying.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. It's called "structural typing", not "structural inheritance". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_typing

Comment: D'oh. You're right. I even have that book (*Types and programming languages*, recommended!!) on my shelf, although I haven't touched it in a while...

Comment: A note from the future (but it seems it was already a fact back in 2009): both [F#](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/06/11/f-duck-typing-and-structural-typing/) and [Scala](http://java.dzone.com/articles/duck-typing-scala-structural) have structural types, without any direct support from the VM.

Answer (score 5):

[DuckTyping for C#](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx)

> Reflection.Emit is used to emit IL that directly calls the original object

I don't think this library will give you compile time errors thought, I am not sure that would be entirely feasible. Use Unit Tests to help compensate for that.

Comment: Released under the Artistic License 2.0!

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using unit tests here. This way you trade the (potentially large) overhead of writing an adapter class for the small overhead of writing a single-line unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's another way in which you would get a compile time error.

However, this is something that Unit Testing is great for.  You would write a unit test to verify that

```
DuckTyper.Adapt<Mallard, IDuck>(mallard);
```

successfully maps.

Answer (score 1):

I know that implicit interfaces (which is what Go interfaces are) were planned for VB 10 (no idea about C#). Unfortunately, they were scrapped before release (I think they didn’t even make it into beta …). It would be nice to see whether they will make an appearance in a future version of .NET.

Of course, the new `dynamic` types can be used to achieve much the same but this is still not the same – implicit interfaces still allow strong typing, which I find important.

Comment: Could you provide links to support your claim concerning implicit interfaces in VB?